# The growth of the error when approximating a differential equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, differential-equations

When solving the differential equation $\ddot\theta + \omega^2 \sin{\theta} = 0$, my text book approximates that $\sin{\theta} = \theta$ and solves the approximated equation $\ddot{\theta} + \omega^2\theta=0$.

However, how do I know the speed of the growth of the error between the real solution and the approximated solution?

Comment: The error is related to \theta. So if in your approximate equation the solution is bounded, so is the error. In this case it will not blow up over time. Though, for some other differential equations, it is much harder to tell if the error will blow up or not when making an approximation.

Comment: This is a very broad question (more suited to Mathematics SE, I think), but it's very dependent on the equation, the boundary conditions and numerical the algorithm implementation.

Comment: simple google search yields https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Period_of_oscillation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The exact solution can be expressed using elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period), and one can in this case actually calculate the growth of the error. It is not going to be terribly illuminating on its own as a formula. Perhaps a better estimate can be found in [plotting the difference in the estimate of the period between the actual and approximated solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#/media/File:Pendulum_period.svg). We can see that the error in period grows roughly quadratically with the initial angle.

This does not tell us the growth rate over time of the error directly, but one could argue that if the above error is $E(\theta_0)=|\hat{\theta}(T(\theta_0))-\theta(T(\theta_0))|$ for a true period $T(\theta_0)$ then the growth rate ought to be roughly $E'(t)\approx E(\theta_0)/T(\theta_0)$. This will be a roughly quadratic function ($E(\theta_0)$) divided by another roughly linear function for small angles ($T(\theta_0)$), so the growth rate over time for small angles will increase roughly linearly with initial angle.

As the angle increases the error becomes worse and worse, especially since the actual trajectory starts to look different from a sine curve oscillation as we approach $\theta\approx \pi$ and the period approaches infinity.